# Simple Cipher Cryptography on Hex File

Tags: substitution-cipher, transposition-cipher

I have been assigned this hex file :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EeidY67VuIddIC-e-xiiKhth1ucMhM_r/view?usp=sharing

The goal is to decrypt it to something meaningful. The only hint given is that the 1st letter of the plaintext is P.

I have tried so far:

Caesar Cipher

```
  Simple key addition/subtraction
  Simple key addition/subtraction but circular in the ASCII range
  Pattern-based (+-+-+ or any other pattern)
```

Substitution

```
  Bigram Substitution (36 unique hex values => no)
  Quadrigram Substitution (61 unique hex values => no)
```

Vigenere

```
  Very hard to find patterns since there is no repeated hex value subset of at least 3 letters
```

Transposition

```
   Even using anagrams but still no
```

If you don`t like to give me the answer a hint would be great.